# Why do we have std::transform_reduce in C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, mapreduce

We have `std::transform` and `std::reduce` functions in C++ standard library . What advantages do we have (except shortening the code) if we use `std::transform_reduce` instead of a combination of `std::transform` and `std::reduce`?

Comment: As far as I understand it takes advantage of parallel execution: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterator-based `<algorithm>` cannot be combined without a temporary copy.

They could, if the functions returned lazy iterators to the transformed ranges, but for better or worse that is not how those functions were designed.

So instead you get the `XXX_YYY` that do both things without extra copies, but not all combinations are available and they still do not scale to multiple operations.

Allowing to combine operations into a computational pipeline of sorts is one of the main advantages of `<ranges>`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::transform_reduce` is in `<numeric>`, and the aim is more like "provide a general and non-sequential version of `std::inner_product`". To be specific, they are all `Init op f(x_0, y_0) op f(x_1, y_1) ... op f(x_n, y_n)`, but `std::inner_product` requires calculation exactly from the beginning to the end one by one, while `std::transform_reduce` are not forced to do so and has a parallel version. Besides, `std::transform_reduce` can also transform by unary operation, i.e. `Init op f(x_0) op f(x_1) ... op f(x_n)`

This is similar to the relationship between `std::inclusive_scan` and `std::partial_sum`.